# Java nested layouts

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout, gridlayoutmanager, nestedlayout

Hy, I'm trying to create a window with a layout like in this picture:

[image: layout]

My ide was to use panels and nest layouts something like that:

[image: layout2]

Here is my code so far, but it is not working properly. How should I do that, what should I do differently, or even my basic concept is wrong?

```
package layout;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import models.People;

public class DetailWindow extends JFrame{

public DetailWindow(People newPeople) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Detail Window");
    
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    frame.add(mainPanel);

    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    frame.add(leftPanel);
    
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    frame.add(rightPanel);
    
    JPanel pictureHolder = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    pictureHolder.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(newPeople.getPic())));
    leftPanel.add(pictureHolder);
    
    JPanel infoHolder = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));
    infoHolder.add(new JTextField(newPeople.getLb_name()));
    infoHolder.add(new JTextField(newPeople.getName()));
    infoHolder.add(new JTextField(newPeople.getLb_occup()));
    infoHolder.add(new JTextField(newPeople.getOccup()));
    infoHolder.add(new JTextField(newPeople.getLb_BD()));
    infoHolder.add(new JTextField(newPeople.getBD()));
    leftPanel.add(infoHolder);

    
    rightPanel.add(new JTextField(newPeople.getName()));
    rightPanel.add(new JTextField(newPeople.getOccup()));
    rightPanel.add(new JTextField(newPeople.getDetail()));
    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.show();
  }
}
```

(The People is a custom class, and in the main I just call the DetailWindow constructor)

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your pictures, I would use the GridBagLayout as explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

The reason for this is that GridBagLayout is the easiest layout when working with multiple panels, it works on the same basis as a basic matrix to position your UI elements, to space them perfectly you can just use a spacer, i.e. an empty layout with a fixed size between the panels.

On the other hand, there are lots of brilliant ide`s out there, I prefer IntelliJ idea, which has a super UI 'generator' and allows you to space your UI exactly the way you want.

Good luck  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you will always have two short and one long texts on the right side, use [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for the panel on the right. Add the big text as BorderLayout.CENTER, and make one more panel (can be GridLayout) for the two shorter texts on the top. Add this second panel as BorderLayout.NORTH.

BorderLayout places one big component in the center, and four others at the edges. GridLayout is like a table and gives equal space for all components, this is not that you try to achieve.

If you need to position multiple components vertically, each taking the needed space only, you need to use the BoxLayout as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651043/how-to-make-boxlayout-behave-as-vertical-flowlayout?rq=1).